# Python: Calculate number of days between two days

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, datetime, timedelta

I have two arrays, reference array and target array. Each array has day of year (DOY) information and I am trying to find the difference in actual number of days between the two. Here is the code,

```
import numpy as np

array_ref = np.array([[362,284],[89,360]])
array_ref
array([[362, 284],
       [ 89, 360]])

array_n = np.array([[2, 365], [194, 10]])
array_n
array([[  2, 365],
       [194,  10]])
```

The absolute difference gives this,

```
print(abs(array_ref-array_n))
[[360  81]
 [105 350]]
```

However, I am trying to achieve this,

```
[[5, 81]
 [105, 15]]
```

I am not sure if I have to use any `datetime` or `timedelta` function or if there is a more simpler way to achieve this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With remainder division.

```
(array_n-array_ref)%365
array([[  5,  81],
       [105,  15]], dtype=int32)
```

In general, you may want to check which subtraction is closer:

```
np.minimum((array_ref-array_n)%365, (array_n-array_ref)%365)
array([[  5,  81],
       [105,  15]], dtype=int32)
```

---

Though this will clearly fail to take leap years into account.

Comment: thanks..this works and I am looking more for non-leap years.